# Can't instantiate NSNumber with shorthand @n type syntax when using enum?

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsnumber, objective-c-literals

I have an `enum` defined like this:

```
typedef enum dataTypes{
    LOW,
    MEDIUM,
    HIGH,
    MAX_DATA_TYPE
} dataTypeEnum;
```

I'd like to be able to instantiate an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s like so:

```
NSArray * numsToUse = @[@LOW, @MEDIUM];
```

This is not compiling. Any insights? Do I have to go with the clunkier `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` for each of these or is there a way around this? (I have considered and rejected `#define` statements for a number of reasons).

Comment: You should use `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, DataTypeEnum) {..}` to define your enum.

Comment: @orkoden what is the difference and why is NS_ENUM preferable?

Comment: [See Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) tl:dr better code completion, better type information for compiler, better Swift interop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use the expression syntax:

```
NSArray * numsToUse = @[@(LOW), @(MEDIUM)];
```

Comment: To add more info - the `@` syntax with no parentheses only works with number literals or `BOOL` literals. All other numeric expressions require the use of parentheses.

Comment: The "why" is that in parentheses the expression is evaluated and then the NSNumber boxing is applied. You can also do `@(1+1)`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the clarification!

Comment: I want to add that the `@` syntax with no parentheses also works in front of macros that are defined to number literals.